# If f is monotone increasing on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

If f is monotone increasing on $\mathbb{R}$,

then for all a$\in \mathbb{R}$ $\lim _{x\rightarrow a+} f(x)$ exits.

my attempt : suppose take $S=\{f(x):x>a\} $and we have to show that inf(S) is real number L.Then show that every sequence $x_n\rightarrow a+$  must have $f(x_n)\rightarrow L$

Comment: Do you know the definition of upper limit? This almost follows from definition.

Comment: I know thow the defintion

Answer (score 2):

The definition is:

> $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = L$ if given $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $x-a < \delta \implies f(x)-L<\epsilon$ (We can remove the modulus as $f$ is increasing).

Now, we know that $f$ is monotone increasing. So we take the candidate limit $S = \inf \{ f(x) : x>a\}$ as you did. Now, we have to fulfill the above criterion.

Take $\epsilon>0$. By the infimum property, $S + \epsilon$ is not a lower bound, so there is some $x_0 > a$ such that $f(x_0) < S + \epsilon$. Now, whenever $a<x< x_0$, $f(x) - S < f(x_0)-S < \epsilon$. Hence, if we take $\delta = x_0-a$, then $x-a < \delta \implies f(x)-s < \epsilon$.

Hence, we are done, and $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = S$.